# Accessing member functions in templated container

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I want to be able to `<<` `val.first()` and `val.second()` element in 
`struct Data<std::pair<F, S>`. `F`, `S` should be generic in the sense that they can be anything specified like `struct Data<int>` (specific type). I don't know how to write the template for `struct Data<std::pair<F, S>` in a way that allows it to only take `struct Data` as `F` or `S`.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct Data;

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Data<T>& val) {
    return val(os);
}

template <typename T>
Data<std::remove_cv_t<T>> data(const T& val) { return { val }; }

template <>
struct Data<int> {
    std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << val;
        return os;
    }
    const int& val;
};

//More struct Data for templatized types for other specific types


template <typename F, typename S>
struct Data<std::pair<F, S> > {
    std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << data(val.first()) << data(val.second());
        return os;
    }
    std::pair<F, S> val;
};

//More struct Data templatized for other container types
```

The error when tested is:

```
 error: called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer
                    os << data(val.first()) << data(val.second());
                               ^~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`first` and `second` are two (public) member **variables** of std::pair, they are not member functions.

```
os << data(val.first()) << data(val.second());
```

becomes

```
os << data(val.first) << data(val.second);
```